# Get the value of text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code

```
<div class="sub-middle-column">
  <div class="div-header">Grandsire
    <a "#", class="table-control-focus sub-header-table-focus" id="table-control-focus-t" >abc</a>
    <ul class="table-controls hide side-action-items">
      <li>
        <a data-remote="true" data-box-no="1" class="find_or_add_horse" href="#">Find/Add Horse</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="go_to_next_horse" data-remote="true">Go to the Next Horse</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="search_horse">
</div>
```

on clicking on `find_or_add_horse` link I want to get the value of the text field using jquery. I tried parent, child and closest but could not get the result. How can I get the value of text field?

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
  // on clicking on find/add horse link I need the value of text field here
});
```

Comment: try $("#search").val()

Comment: sheez, i almost hear people typing the answer faster than me

Comment: @doniyor not only posting the answer, later editing it faster than me...

Comment: This question is for the very first time on SO. OP searched and didn't find anything here. Even on the internet. Huh...

Comment: @MiljanPuzović no way

Comment: @AlokAnand hahaha, right dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/pyPtW/

You can use parents to find the root element, then use find on that element to get the input.

```
console.log($(this).parents('.sub-middle-column').find('.search_horse').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
    var value = $('#search').val();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PrqD/)

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()`:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
       alert($('#search').val());
    });
```

if you have multiple `sub-middle-column` div then try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
       alert($(this).closest('.sub-middle-column').find('.search_horse').val());
    });
```

Comment: @Anton beat you by 49 seconds

Answer (score 0):

`.val();` is for input fields, `.text()` for other html containers like `p`, `div`..

AND dont forget to `$.trim();` the input, cos hopefully you dont want whitespaces around the input text

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
   var inputtextvalue = $.trim($("#search").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function(){
     var textValue= $('#search').val();
      });
```